# Java anagram working code, in assistant of understanding the concept of the code

Tags: java

```
public static boolean anagramTest(String one, String two){  // two parameter and boolean (true or false)                                        

    String a = one.toLowerCase();   // making value into lower case                                     
    String b = two.toLowerCase();                                       

    if (a.length() != b.length()){     // if value in a is not equal to b, return false                                     
      return false;                                     
    }                                       

    int[] check = new int[50];    // new array called counter with 50 space                                     
    int difference = 0;     // new int labled checker                                       

    for (int i=0;i<a.length(); i++){     // for loop for first length                                       
        int o = (int) a.charAt(i) - 97;  //making char into array index, a numeric value for a?                                       
        if (check[o] >= 0){    // ---                                     
            difference++;                                     
        } else {                                        
            difference--;           // ---                                        
        }                                       
        check[o]++;  // ----                                        

        int t = (int) b.charAt(i) - 97;      //making char into array index                                     
        if (check[t] <= 0){                                     
          difference++;                                     
        } else {                                        
          difference--;                                     
        }                                       
        check[t]--;                                     
    }
}
```

I created a code with a `main` with the help of online resources, but I vaguely understand how it functions and want to make sure I fully understand the concept, so first I have two parameter put into new string to convert into lowercase and if `a` is not the same as `b`, it is `false`. So I created a new array and int. A for loop with new int where a value `charAt` but why `97`, apparently u subtract from `a` to `z`? Then it checks the increase and decrease in differences and goes the same for `b` value and ends with a return as value `0`.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking-you explicitly state in the comments what's happening, and simple debugging or logging should answer anything else.

Comment: Do you have an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) handy?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's clearer to understand in stages:

1) The `check` array keeps track of the frequency of the letters seen in string `a` minus the frequency of the letters seen in string `b`.  In other words, at the end of the function, `check[c-'a']` denotes the number of times the character `'c'` occurred in the string `a` minus the number of times it occurred in the string `b`.(The ASCII code for the character `a` is 97 by the way).

2) Now from here, you want to make sure the `check` array is all zero -- ie: the frequencies of the characters in both strings are balanced.  If so, the two strings are anagrams.  If not, the `difference` value computed is going to be the sum of the absolute values of the check array.